# How do you insert newlines and hyperlinks into Google Forms question help text?

Tags: google-apps-script, hyperlink, newline, google-apps, google-forms

I need to be able to insert both hyperlinks and newlines into the help text of my Google Forms using Google App Script. Neither is possible.

For links I have tried (to no effect):

- `http://link.com/path`
- `<a href='http://link.com/path'>http://link.com/path</a>`

For newlines I have tried (to no effect):

- `\n`
- `\\n`
- `\n`

My code follows:

```js
function createForm() {
  var form = FormApp.create('Amazon Open Source Project Classification');

  form.setDescription("This form is for labeling open source projects using the project url and description with the following 4 categories:\n\n1) \
API - this is an API library that can only be used to access an Amazon Web Services (AWS) API\n2) EDUCATION - this is an educational project or example \
of how to use an AWS API\n3) GENERAL - this is a general purpose open source project with utility for the public\n4) DATASET - this is a dataset \
published by researchers as part of their researchz\n") 

  form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
    .setTitle("What category does the project fall under?")
    .setHelpText("<a href='http://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs'>http://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs</a>\n\nThe Alexa Skills Kit SDK for Node.js helps you get a skill up and running quickly, letting you focus on skill logic instead of boilerplate code.")
    .setChoiceValues(['API','EDUCATION', 'GENERAL', 'DATASET'])

  Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
  Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());
}
```

Comment: Is it possible manually?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to set an hyperlink in that field as the method [setHelpText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#sethelptexttext) requires a String parameter and the Forms UI doesn't interpret it as HTML.

However, you can submit a Feature Request into Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) using the Component `Public Trackers > G Suite Developers > Apps Script` (as this would be for the Apps Script [FormApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app)).